# Spark SQL window function range boundaries with condition

Tags: sql, apache-spark-sql, window-functions

My data looks like the following:

```
         Sequence|       type      | sg       |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
|              1| Pump             |3         |
|              2| Pump             |2         |
|              3| Inject           |4         |
|              4| Pump             |5         |
|              5| Pump             |3         | 
|              6| pump             |6         |
|              7| Inject           |7         |
|              8| Inject           |8         |
|              9| Pump             |9         |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
```

I want to add a new column and check the previous `type` value.

If the previous `type` value is `Pump`, set the value of the new column to the value of the corresponding `sg`.

If it's `inject`, then get the sum of all the previous rows' `sg` values, until a row with a `Pump` `type` is found (its `sg` value being included in the sum).

EX:
For `Sequence = 2`, previous row's `type` is `Pump`, so the new column's value should be that of the corresponding `sg` column: 3.

For `Sequence = 9`, previous row's `type` is `Inject`, so the new column's value will be the sum of the 3 previous rows' `sg` column, since `Sequence = 6` row is the first previous row with a `type = Pump`. The new column's value will then be `8 + 7 + 6 = 21`.

Final output should be like:

```
       Sequence|       type      | sg       |  New sg |
+-----------------+----------------+----------+--------+
|              1| Pump             |3         |-
|              2| Pump             |2         |3
|              3| Inject           |4         |2
|              4| Pump             |5         |6
|              5| Pump             |3         |5
|              6| pump             |6         |3
|              7| Inject           |7         |6
|              8| Inject           |8         |7
|              9| Pump             |9         |21
+-----------------+----------------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your rules, this is just a bunch of window functions.  The trick is to aggregate by group for the "pump" values with "inject"s.  A cumulative sum of "pump"s finds the groups.

Then the query is:

```
select t.*,
        (case when prev_type = 'Pump' then sg
              else lag(pump_sg) over (order by id)
         end) as your_value
from (select t.*,
             sum(sg) over (partition by pump_grp) as pump_sg
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(sg) over (order by id) as prev_sg,
                   lag(type) over (order by id) as prev_type,
                 sum(case when type = 'Pump' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as pump_grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

I think your rules are overly complicated, and you don't need a special case for the previous row being "pump".  So:

```
select t.*,
       lag(pump_sg) over (order by id) as your_value
from (select t.*,
             sum(sg) over (partition by pump_grp) as pump_sg
      from (select t.*,
                 sum(case when type = 'Pump' then 1 else 0 end) over (order by id) as pump_grp
            from t
           ) t
     ) t;
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon :) !!.